# Method 'Worksheets' of object '_global' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am completed stumped by this error at the moment and have not found a solution after a lot of searching.  The error only occurs on every other execution of the code.  I'll just post the section of the code dealing with Excel, as that's obviously where the problem is.  All variables have been defined, but I'll include my definitions of the important ones.

```
Dim msEX As Excel.Application
Dim exBook As Excel.Workbook

Set msEX = New Excel.Application
msEX.Visible = True

Set exBook = msEX.Workbooks.Open(CurrentProject.Path & "\Bookings.xlsx")
exBook.Activate

If SheetExists("Template (2)", exBook) = True Then
    msEX.DisplayAlerts = False
    exBook.Worksheets("Template (2)").Delete
    msEX.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
exBook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets("Template")

If SheetExists(sheetName, exBook) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Name = sheetName & " (old)"
    exBook.Worksheets("Template (2)").Name = sheetName
    Do While Err <> 0
        Err.Clear
        newSheetName = InputBox("Please enter a new name for the sheet", "Worksheet name is taken")
        If newSheetName = "" Then
            exBook.Close True
            MsgBox ("Invalid Name, sheet not created")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        exBook.Worksheets("Template (2)").Name = newSheetName
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
Else
    exBook.Worksheets("Template (2)").Name = sheetName
End If

exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A1").Value = r!Course
exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range("A2").Value = r![Start Date]
exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range("B3").Value = venName & " " & r![Start Time]

For i = 0 To i = UBound(learnerNames) - LBound(learnerNames) + 1
    exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range("C" & i + 6).Value = learnerNames(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To i = UBound(learnerPhones) - LBound(learnerPhones) + 1
    exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range("D" & i + 6).Value = learnerPhones(i)
Next i

For i = 0 To i = UBound(learnerEmails) - LBound(learnerEmails) + 1
    exBook.Worksheets(sheetName).Range("E" & i + 6).Value = learnerEmails(i)
Next i

exBook.Save

End If
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: never use `On Error Resume Next`

Comment: At a guess, you meant to use: `exBook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=exBook.Worksheets("Template")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> exBook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=Worksheets("Template")
> ```

Only the above line has an unqualified `Worksheets` call. Change it into

```
exBook.Worksheets("Template").Copy After:=exBook.Worksheets("Template")
'                                         ^^^^^^^
```